# Problems using the space key to enable and disable object in Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a game in Unity 2D where there is a box, and I was trying to make the box attack other boxes. To do that I created a child object on the player box that is initially disabled, and my idea was that when I pressed the spacebar I enabled the child object, that has a collider that can collide with other boxes so that I can hit stuff.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class playerAttack : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject attackArea;
    public float timer = 0f;
    public float attackTime = 0.25f;
    public bool attacking = false;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            attackArea = transform.GetChild(0).gameObject;
            Attack();
        }

        if(attacking)
        {
            timer += Time.deltaTime;
            if (timer >= attackTime)
            {
                attacking = false;
                attackArea = transform.GetChild(0).gameObject;
                attackArea.SetActive(false);
            }
        }

    }

    void Attack()
    {
        attacking = true;
        attackArea.SetActive(true);
    }

}
```

My script works like this: when I press the space key it enables the child object, which I called attackArea, then it runs a timer that disables the attackArea after 0.25 seconds, so I can attack again. What is happening is that when I run the game I can attack only 1 time, then the script stops working.

I tried to rewrite the Attack function inside the first "if" statement, so that I don't need to call it, but that makes no difference. I have no clue on what to do neither on how to search for the answer, because I am a beginner relearning the basics.

Comment: you never reset your timer to zero

Comment: please refrain from using the tag `unityscript` for `c#` unity projects